# Server Side Rendering - renderToString returns empty html

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to render react application on server, but it seems that renderToString function doesn't render markup properly, when I do console.log(markup) I'm getting something like this:

```
<div data-reactroot="" data-reactid="1" data-react-checksum="-1424217736">
<!-- react-empty: 2 --><!-- react-empty: 3 --><!-- react-empty: 4 --><!-- react-empty: 5 --></div>
```

My code looks like this:

```
app.use('*', (req, res) => {

  const context = {}
  const store = configureStore()


  const markup = renderToString(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <StaticRouter
        location={req.url}
        context={context}
      >
        <Routes/>
      </StaticRouter>
    </Provider>
  )

  console.log(markup)

  if (context.url) {
    // Somewhere a `<Redirect>` was rendered
    redirect(301, context.url)
  } else {
    // we're good, send the response
    res.send(`
      <!doctype html>
      <head>
      <meta name="google-site-verification" content="P5pcBDBR0SrpH4kFMOp5Ush5JxDdG-3oPhjKO8Zf5WE" />
      </head>
      <body>
      <div id="app">${markup}</div>
      </body>
    `)


}
})
```

I'm using React-Router v4

Comment: I'd have to see your <Routes /> but that looks right. Those react-empty comments are placeholders for routes that are not rendered.

Comment: Here is my routes function: 

export const Routes = () => (
 <div>
  <Route path='/baza' component={KnowledgeBase}/>
  <Route exact path='/baza' component={Categories}/>
  <Route path='/baza/:articleurl' component={Article}/>
  <Route exact path='/baza/error' component={EffectTest}/>
 </div>
)

and imported on the top like so:
const { Routes } = require('../client/routes')

Comment: And what path are you using to access your app? Are you going to something like `http://localhost/`? If so, you have no route setup for `path="/"` and you would not render any routes.